# I am getting the error"Remote URL test failed: protocol 'git clone HTTPS ' is not supported" when i enter the url field

Tags: java, android, android-studio, github, bitbucket

When I enter the HTTPS URL given in the Bitbucket site in Android Studio when I click "define remote" it gives me the error

> Remote URL test failed: protocol 'git clone https' is not supported

I have used the SSH URL and that gives me the error

> Remote URL test failed: Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '18.205.93.0' to the list of known hosts.
>
> Could not read from remote repository.

I have even tried to switch the built-in option in settings from native but then it keeps prompting me for the login and password even after me entering the login and password.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't include `git clone` in the remote information box. That's a command that you might run on the command line to clone the repo.

Your remote should just be the remote URL, e.g.

```
https://bitbucket.org/user/repo
```